# Converting Time datatype to character string in R language

Tags: r, difftime

When selecting the 'Time' column from the dataframe, I get the time in "%H:%M:%S" format

```
> tail(sf_arrest[,c("Time")],1)
# A tibble: 1 × 1
      Time
    <time>
1 06:44:00
```

I would like to convert this to character format like "06:44:00". For some reason, "as.character" gives the difftime output than the expected one

```
> as.character(tail(sf_arrest[,c("Time")],1))
[1] "24240"
```

How to perform direct character conversion?

Comment: What is the package you used?  Try `as.character(sf_arrest[["Time"]])`

Comment: > as.character(tail(sf_arrest["Time"],1))
[1] "24240". it's the same output.

Comment: I showed a different syntax with `[[` and not `[`.  So, if you are using completely different syntax and saying that it is the same output, it is not right

Comment: Sorry. you are right. > as.character(tail(sf[["Time"]],1))
[1] "06:44:00" . It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is a `tibble`, we can extract the column with `[[` instead of `[` and convert to `character`

```
as.character(sf_arrest[["Time"]])
```